# AJAX request specified as POST, but sent as GET

Tags: jquery, ajax

The server keeps on treating any request from my AJAX method as a GET request despite setting the method as POST. Any idea why this is happening?

```js
function postToServer(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, feedback) {

  console.log(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, feedback);

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: " http://xxxxxx.com/postto",
    data: "",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Note that since jQuery 1.9.0, `method` is an alias for `type`. See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and the [changeset from 2012](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/081c4efcf7736433d2fb5702e7bd4f8616426af2). Based on the answer you accepted, I assume you're using a jQuery version prior to 1.9.0, though you have not specified. I suggest using a more recent version of jQuery -- your code is [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/fgxq5kzk/1/) with jQuery 1.9.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no option call `method:` it's `type:`

```
function postToServer(firstName,lastName,emailAddress,feedback){
    console.log(firstName, lastName, emailAddress,feedback);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: " http://xxxxxx.com/postto",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){        
        console.log(data);

        }
     });

    }
```

Comment: ah my bad! Thank you.

Comment: Since jQuery 1.9.0, `method` is an alias for `type`. See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Also see the [changeset from 2012](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/081c4efcf7736433d2fb5702e7bd4f8616426af2).

Comment: yeah but he doesn't use 1.9.0

Comment: That can be assumed, but it is not specified by the OP. You might want to clarify that there is no `method` setting *prior to jQuery 1.9.0*.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
type : 'POST'
```

and not

```
method : 'POST
```

Comment: Since jQuery 1.9.0, `method` is an alias for `type`. See [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Also see the [changeset from 2012](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/081c4efcf7736433d2fb5702e7bd4f8616426af2).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$.post( "http://xxxxxx.com/postto", "", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```